# Visualize routes in veins examples

Tags: omnet++

When i run the veins example, i don't visualize the routes and buildings of the erlangen map. I show just geometric forms like squares, rectangles and nodes pass by them. I need to visualize the really photo of the map of erlangen when running veins example.
It is possible to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

Both OMNeT++ and SUMO can show a background image in a running simulation. This will likely need a lot of manual tweaking to look good though.